# Getting error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, docker

I use docker in windows and when I wrote
`docker run c0cdc mysql MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password`
It gave me the error `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

Comment: can you share the `Dockerfile`? and how are you connecting to `MySQL? Are you connecting to Mysql which is on your local system or is it also a container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folllowing steps solved the problem:

```
 1. touch /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
 2. touch /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
 3. chown -R mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
 4. chown -R mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
 5. chmod -R 644 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Now restart the mysql-server as:

```
service mysql-server restart
```